# Finding the maximum value between two columns where one of them is shifted

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

My DataFrame is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
       'a': [20, 9, 31, 40],
       'b': [1, 10, 17, 30],
    }
)
```

Expected output: Creating column `c`

```
    a   b   c
0  20   1  20
1   9  10  20
2  31  17  17
3  40  30  31
```

Steps:

`c` is the maximum value between `df.b` and `df.a.shift(1).bfill()`.

[image]

My attempt:

```
df['temp'] = df.a.shift(1).bfill()
df['c'] = df[['temp', 'b']].max(axis=1)
```

Is it the cleanest way / best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the temporary column, then you can replace values on the shifted column using `where()` in a one-liner.

```py
df['c'] = df['a'].shift(1).bfill().where(lambda x: x>df['b'], df['b'])
```

This is similar to the `combine()` method posted in the other answer, but this one does a vectorized comparison while, `combine()` does it element-wise so this should be much faster as the length of the dataframe increase.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
       'a': [20, 9, 31, 40],
       'b': [1, 10, 17, 30],
    }
)
df['c'] = df['a'].shift(1).bfill().combine(df['b'], max)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    a   b     c
0  20   1  20.0
1   9  10  20.0
2  31  17  17.0
3  40  30  31.0
```

Answer (score 1):

use numpy `fmax`, fast and simple way

```
import numpy as np
df['c'] = np.fmax(df['a'].shift().bfill(), df['b'])
```

df

```
    a   b     c
0  20   1  20.0
1   9  10  20.0
2  31  17  17.0
3  40  30  31.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One point of optimization is `df.a.shift(1).bfill()`, which is not so efficient (you evaluate all values just to fill the first one). The other is the use of [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) (or [`fmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fmax.html) to ignore NaNs):

```
df['c'] = np.maximum(df['a'].shift(1, fill_value=df['a'].iat[0]),
                     df['b'])
```

Output:

```
    a   b   c
0  20   1  20
1   9  10  20
2  31  17  17
3  40  30  31
```

`bfill` is much slower than simply providing the `fill_value`:

```
# s = pd.Series(range(1_000_000))

# s.shift(1).bfill()
7.88 ms ± 400 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# s.shift(1, fill_value=s.iat[0])
474 µs ± 1.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```